# Exclude vendor files from Simplecov reports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, code-coverage, simplecov

I just want to exclude the vendor gems from being shown with the coverage report, how to do that?

Here is how my coverage report looks like:

[image: Report]

Answer (score 22):

You can exclude the vendors folder adding a filter in the spec_helper.rb or where you define the configuration for SimpleCov

```
SimpleCov.start 'rails' do
  add_filter 'vendor'
end
```

Comment: Adding such a `.simplecov` file at the root of your project directory also allows `bashcov` to ignore those directories/files.

Answer (score 20):

Here is how I handled it, figured out with their documentation!

```
SimpleCov.profiles.define 'no_vendor_coverage' do
  load_profile 'rails'
  add_filter 'vendor' # Don't include vendored stuff
end

SimpleCov.start 'no_vendor_coverage'
```