# Where to start modifying BashCov to implement --exclude option?

Tags: ruby, code-coverage, simplecov, bats-core

### Context

While trying to build a/the `--exclude`/`--ignore` option to [bashcov](https://github.com/infertux/bashcov/blob/master/features/step_definitions/bashcov_steps.rb) I am experiencing some difficulties in determining where to start.

Bashcov does not support the `--exclude`/`--ignore` option yet, as can be seen from the following output to: `bashcov --help`:

```bash
bashcov --help
Usage: bashcov [options] [--] <command> [options]
Examples:
    bashcov ./script.sh
    bashcov --skip-uncovered ./script.sh
    bashcov -- ./script.sh --some --flags
    bashcov --skip-uncovered -- ./script.sh --some --flags

Specific options:
    -s, --skip-uncovered             Do not report uncovered files
    -m, --mute                       Do not print script output
        --bash-path PATH             Path to Bash executable
        --root PATH                  Project root directory
        --command-name NAME          Value to use as SimpleCov.command_name

Common options:
    -h, --help                       Show this message
        --version                    Show version
```

### Motivation

Bashcov includes non-project related files and folders such as the `.git` folder, and the bats unit test modules in `test/libs`. This makes it difficult to understand how well the project code itself is actually tested:

[image]
For example, the above report shows a 17% coverage, even though of 100% of the custom project bash code lines are tested.

### Options

1. Bashcov relies on simplecov, so if I could modify bashcov to pass the bashcov `--exclude`/`--ignore` commands to simplecov, that may be sufficient. I found the `bashcov` arguments are parsed [here](https://github.com/infertux/bashcov/blob/247fcb7e0c753eff8afdfa10ca00d5e025d06bdc/lib/bashcov.rb).
2. If Bashcov compiles the list of files to be checked itself, I could modify bashcov to only include those files if they are not within the `--exclude`/`--ignore` directories/list. However, I do not yet know whether bashcov does this and if yes where, or whether it relies on simplecov to do that.

#### Details Option II:

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49389181/7437143) that shows how the `SimpleCov.start` line can be modified to add a filter/exclude list. In bashcov, that `SimpleCov.start` line can be found [here](https://github.com/infertux/bashcov/blob/247fcb7e0c753eff8afdfa10ca00d5e025d06bdc/bin/bashcov#L17), however I do not yet know how to compile, build and install bashcov locally (without getting the default version from `sudo apt install bashcov on Ubuntu 22.10).

### Question

What would be a practical place to start modifying bashcov to build the `--exclude`/`--ignore` function?

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed to modify bashcov. The `--exclude`/`--ignore` option is supported through a `SimpleCov` configuration file. In the root directory of one's own project, one can add a `.simplecov` file with content:

```yaml
SimpleCov.start do
  minimum_coverage 15
  add_filter "test/libs"
  add_filter "/.git/"
end
```

And that ensures the coverage report and result ignore those `test/libs/` and `.git/` directories.